# Can I use a custom shell with upstart script stanza?

Tags: services, upstart, scripts

I'm writing a few daemons implemented in pure shell script and would like to use zsh(powerful substitutions, modules with socket/tcp handling, etc) instead of the default /bin/sh. Can I tell the 'script' stanza to use a custom shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [documented] way to switch from /bin/sh as the main shell script run in. However, you could just wrap your script up in zsh. I do this with bash in various places (usually find's -exec clause):

```
zsh -c "do things...; more things..."
```

A slightly more elegant way would be:

```
script
zsh -- <<EOF

# do stuff here

EOF
end script
```

Comment: Simple but works nicely. It would be better if upstart provided a native way to use a custom shell, so editors like vim wouldn't loose syntax highlighting/indentation in the heredoc.